# Mail not sending to main domain

Tags: linux, email, email-server, exim

server (main server hosts domain)

server 2 (hosts other sites and all)
mail sends to and from just fine. however, if i send to an e-mail on SERVER from SERVER2 using the main domain site on SERVER i dont get it.

EXAMPLE:

```
2012-06-08 08:35:34 cwd=/var/spool/exim 3 args: /usr/sbin/exim -Mc 1ScyPd-001rYs-Qu
2012-06-08 08:35:34 1ScyPd-001rYs-Qu => DOMAINUSRNAME <alert@SERVER1DOMAIN.com> R=localuser T=local_delivery
2012-06-08 08:35:34 1ScyPd-001rYs-Qu Completed
2012-06-08 08:35:40 cwd=/etc/csf 4 args: /usr/sbin/sendmail -f alerts@SERVER2NAME.SERVER1DOMAIN.com -t
2012-06-08 08:35:40 1ScyPk-001rby-Me <= notice@SERVER2NAME.SERVER1DOMAIN.com U=root P=local S=700 T="lfd on SERVER2NAME.SERVER1DOMAIN.com: WHM/cPanel root access alert from 24.43.62.12" for alert@SERVER1DOMAIN.com
```

shows its sending but i never get it in my mailboxes on SERVER but SERVER gets mail from other remotes like hotmail ect... and SERVER2 sends just fine to places like HOTMAIL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks to me like server2 delivered it locally, because it believes it handles mail for server1domain.

```
T=local_delivery
```

is the giveaway.

I can only assume somewhere in the CPanel config, you're telling server2 that it's in the same domain as server1, and hence mail to @domain is being handled by server2.

Final fix: removing main domain from localdomains and adding to remotedomains.

Comment: I'm running CPanel and the domain that is on SERVER1 I also created on SERVER2 so could that maybe be the problem?
I did see the notice@s2.s1d.com under /etc/localdomains and in exim.conf i have domainlist local_domains = lsearch;/etc/localdomains

Comment: Don't really understand your comment - but basically, I stand by what I'm suggesting, server2 believes it handles mail for the server1domain part of the mail address, and so it delivers it locally.

Comment: So I need to find a way to change local delivery to remote or something?

Comment: You need to tell server2 it does not handle the mail for server1's domain.  It's hard to provide much more advice without knowing specifically the config and the domains in question.

Comment: Wish I knew where CPanel kept all this stuff and what I was looking for. I never was the best at the e-mail side of things. At least I have something to start working with. But this is the exim config http://pastebin.com/FSmFuA88

Comment: Fixed by removing main domain from localdomains and adding to remotedomains.